# How to set flags in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, boolean, flags

I need to write a program that asks the user for array size and then the user will input these values. After that, I need to ask the user to remove one of those values and the program will replace it with a zero. SO i need to write an if statement inside a for loop to check if the number the user inputed is found in the array or not the replace it with a zero. However i am required to use a boolean and a flag and im not sure how to do that. so far i got this but does not work.

```
System.out.println("Enter the value to search and remove: ");
        // Use your Scanner to get a value for search
         int valueToRemove = scan.nextInt();

    // To search, we can iterate all values, record the index of target (t),
    // and then shift to the left values from t to the end.
    boolean isFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
         if (i == valueToRemove){

         }
        //     Set a flag isFound
        // 
        if (isFound = true) {
        //     if i + 1 is available
        //         move element i + 1 to index i
            i = (i+1);
        }
        //     if i + 1 is not available
         else
        //         set element i as zero
         i=0;
    }

    if (isFound)
    {
        System.out.println("Search element found");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Search element NOT found");   
    }


    // ============================================================
    // Display the final array

    System.out.println("\nThe final array");

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        // Print ith element, do NOT include line break
        System.out.print(integerArray[i]+ ", " );
    }

    // Print a line break
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Comment: *but does not work* - what exactly doesn’t work?

Comment: Where is your array of values? You are not updating the array, you are only updating the "i" variable.

Comment: In your code you commented _move the element to the right_. That isn't in your description of the question...

Comment: Is this a homework exercise? If so please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/). Please understand that stackoverflow is for helping people with programming, not programming for them.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop use this code only:

```
isFound = (a[i] == valueToRemove);
if (isFound) {
    a[i] = 0;
    break;
}
```

`isFound` is the flag and it gets `true` if the array item `a[i]` is equal to `valueToRemove`.  
 If this flag is `true` it changes the value of the item to 0 `enter code here`and exits the loop.  
I used `a` for the array, change it to the name of your variable.  
I guess `arraySize` is a variable holding the size of the array.